# Trying to get hostent from a name-less server

Tags: ldap, kerberos, fedora, freeipa

I'm having some issues with my freeIPA.

Which I think is leading to the issue - each time I am leaving computer for few hours (or sometimes minutes), I have to re do

```
$ kinit user
```

in order to get an access to shared folders.

Found some related(?) issues on the net regarding missing name in "krb5info" file but without any solution so I am not sure even where to start looking into.

Here is a snippet from sssd_home.mydomain.com.log file:

```
[root@myworkstation sssd]# tail -n100 sssd_home.mydomain.com.log
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: end of ldap_result list
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_method_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus method sssd.dataprovider.pamHandler on /sssd
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.pam]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_pam_handler_send] (0x0100): Got request with the following data
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] command: SSS_PAM_PREAUTH
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] domain: home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] user: myuser@home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] service: sudo
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] tty: /dev/pts/1
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] ruser: myuser
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] rhost: 
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] authtok type: 0 (No authentication token available)
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] newauthtok type: 0 (No authentication token available)
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] priv: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] cli_pid: 1841161
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] logon name: not set
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] flags: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#126349] DP Request [PAM Preauth #126349]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.pam CID #12] Flags [0000].
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#126349] Number of active DP request: 1
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Domain home.mydomain.com is Active
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Domain home.mydomain.com is Active
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_auth_queue_send] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Wait queue of user [myuser@home.mydomain.com] is empty, running request [0x55a38ee69a80] immediately.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_setup] (0x4000): [RID#126349] No mapping for: myuser@home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): [RID#126349] Trying to resolve service 'IPA'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Status of server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Port status of port 0 for server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_resolve_service_activate_timeout] (0x2000): [RID#126349] Resolve timeout [dns_resolver_timeout] set to 6 seconds
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Status of server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Saving the first resolved server
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x0200): [RID#126349] Found address for server myipaserver.home.mydomain.com: [10.0.1.10] TTL 7200
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [ipa_resolve_callback] (0x0400): [RID#126349] Constructed uri 'ldap://myipaserver.home.mydomain.com'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_get_server_hostent] (0x0020): [RID#126349] Bug: Trying to get hostent from a name-less server
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [write_krb5info_file_from_fo_server] (0x0020): [RID#126349] Server without name and address found in list.
(2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_get_server_hostent] (0x0020): [RID#126350] Bug: Trying to get hostent from a name-less server
********************** PREVIOUS MESSAGE WAS TRIGGERED BY THE FOLLOWING BACKTRACE:
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [write_krb5info_file_from_fo_server] (0x0020): [RID#126349] Server without name and address found in list.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_add_krb5info_offline_callback] (0x4000): [RID#126349] Removal callback already available for service [IPA].
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [unique_filename_destructor] (0x2000): [RID#126349] Unlinking [/var/lib/sss/pubconf/.krb5info_dummy_NOGn1e]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [unlink_dbg] (0x2000): [RID#126349] File already removed: [/var/lib/sss/pubconf/.krb5info_dummy_NOGn1e]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Domain home.mydomain.com is Active
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): [RID#126349] Setting up signal handler up for pid [1841267]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): [RID#126349] Signal handler set up for pid [1841267]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [write_pipe_handler] (0x0400): [RID#126349] All data has been sent!
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [read_pipe_handler] (0x0400): [RID#126349] EOF received, client finished
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [parse_krb5_child_response] (0x1000): [RID#126349] child response: status code: 0 (Success), msg type: 11 (Password prompting is possible), len: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [_be_fo_set_port_status] (0x8000): [RID#126349] Setting status: PORT_WORKING. Called from: src/providers/krb5/krb5_auth.c: krb5_auth_done: 1086
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0100): [RID#126349] Marking port 0 of server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' as 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [set_server_common_status] (0x0100): [RID#126349] Marking server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' as 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0400): [RID#126349] Marking port 0 of duplicate server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' as 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [check_wait_queue] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Wait queue for user [myuser@home.mydomain.com] is empty.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_auth_queue_done] (0x1000): [RID#126349] krb5_auth_queue request [0x55a38ee69a80] done.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_req_done] (0x0400): [RID#126349] DP Request [PAM Preauth #126349]: Request handler finished [0]: Success
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [_dp_req_recv] (0x0400): [RID#126349] DP Request [PAM Preauth #126349]: Receiving request data.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#126349] DP Request [PAM Preauth #126349]: Request removed.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#126349] Number of active DP request: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): sssd.dataprovider.pamHandler: Success
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [child_sig_handler] (0x1000): [RID#126349] Waiting for child [1841267].
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0100): [RID#126349] child [1841267] finished successfully.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:23): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_method_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus method sssd.dataprovider.pamHandler on /sssd
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.pam]
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_pam_handler_send] (0x0100): Got request with the following data
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] command: SSS_PAM_AUTHENTICATE
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] domain: home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] user: myuser@home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] service: sudo
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] tty: /dev/pts/1
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] ruser: myuser
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] rhost: 
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] authtok type: 1 (Password)
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] newauthtok type: 0 (No authentication token available)
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] priv: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] cli_pid: 1841161
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] logon name: not set
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): [CID #12] flags: 0
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#126350] DP Request [PAM Authenticate #126350]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.pam CID #12] Flags [0000].
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#126350] Number of active DP request: 1
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Domain home.mydomain.com is Active
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Domain home.mydomain.com is Active
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_auth_queue_send] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Wait queue of user [myuser@home.mydomain.com] is empty, running request [0x55a38eda2f70] immediately.
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [krb5_setup] (0x4000): [RID#126350] No mapping for: myuser@home.mydomain.com
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): [RID#126350] Trying to resolve service 'IPA'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Status of server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Port status of port 0 for server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_resolve_service_activate_timeout] (0x2000): [RID#126350] Resolve timeout [dns_resolver_timeout] set to 6 seconds
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Status of server 'myipaserver.home.mydomain.com' is 'working'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x1000): [RID#126350] Saving the first resolved server
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x0200): [RID#126350] Found address for server myipaserver.home.mydomain.com: [10.0.1.10] TTL 7200
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [ipa_resolve_callback] (0x0400): [RID#126350] Constructed uri 'ldap://myipaserver.home.mydomain.com'
   *  (2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [fo_get_server_hostent] (0x0020): [RID#126350] Bug: Trying to get hostent from a name-less server
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2022-05-24  9:57:27): [be[home.mydomain.com]] [write_krb5info_file_from_fo_server] (0x0020): [RID#126350] Server without name and address found in list.
```